# Troubles converting processing to p5.js with PVectors

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have been trying off and on to get this java `processing` program to work and it seems REALLY simple but for some reason, I can not figure out what is going wrong. I am not used to using `PVectors`, so I am assuming it has something to do with that. I will post the original, and then my non-working `p5.js` attempt.

I have been stuck on this for soooo long. I actually learned p5.js before I learned original processing so maybe that is why I'm making a dumb mistake.
Currently, all I am getting is a blank screen. Also, I am running on linux and finding a linux version with actually visible and working debug in an IDE is hard and so is getting `p5.js` mode working in general. I've just been using trial and error by hosting it online. So I can't figure out what IDE would interpret the errors it is giving.

Original, works in Java IDE:

```java
PImage img;

void setup(){
   size(500, 500, P2D); //width and height should be similar to the picture's dimensions
    
    img = loadImage("turner.jpg");
}

void draw(){
    img.resize(500,500);
    int len = img.pixels.length;
    //print(len);
    //print(img.width * img.height);
    loadPixels();
    for(int x = 0; x < img.width; x++){ // by row
      for(int y = 0; y < img.height; y++) { // by column
         int i = x + y * img.width; // i = index of grid columns
         float n = warp(x, y, .003, 255); 
         int offset = (i-int(n)); //%len; // with a modulo the offset should wrap around 
         if (offset<0){
          offset = 0; 
         }
         color c = img.pixels[offset]; // --> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
         
         pixels[i] = color(c);
         }
      }
    updatePixels();
}

       
float warp(int _x, int _y, float factor, int n_range) {
    float n1 = noise((_x+0.0) * factor, (_y+0.0) * factor) * n_range;
    float n2 = noise((_x+5.2) * factor, (_y+1.3) * factor) * n_range;
    PVector q = new PVector(n1, n2);
            
    float n3 = noise(((_x + q.x * 4) + 1.7) * factor, ((_y + q.y * 4) + 9.2) * factor) * n_range;
    float n4 = noise(((_x + q.x * 4) + 8.3) * factor, ((_y + q.y * 4) + 2.8) * factor) * n_range;
    PVector r = new PVector(n3, n4);
                
    return noise((_x + r.x * 4) * factor, (_y + r.y * 4) * factor) * n_range;
}
```

Comment: I think you should change the tag from Javascript to Java.

Comment: You can use inspect element to help with debugging once you have it hosted online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p5.js` deals with images a bit differently to processing, see [docs.](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image)

Key Points:

- In `processing` the image array would be an array of numbers with each group of 4 in a row representing r g b a for each pixel. But by using `image.set()` and `image.get()` methods you can avoid that, and you can access using only `x` and `y`.
- Have a look at `p5.Vector`, it is basically a `PVector` equivalent.

The following works for me, can't guarantee that it's optimised. I tried to translate yours as closely as possible. (Converting from `processing` to `p5.js` should really be fully automated by now.)

```js
var img;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage("turner.jpg");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500, P2D);
}

function draw() {
    img.resize(500, 500);
    
    var len = img.pixels.length;
    // pr___parseint(len);
    // pr___parseint(img.width * img.height);
    img.loadPixels();
    
    for (var x = 0; x < img.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < img.height; y++) {
            var i = x + y * img.width;
            
            var n = warp(x, y, 0.003, 255);
            // %len; // with a modulo the offset should wrap around
            var offset = (i - int(n));
            if (offset < 0) {
                offset = 0;
            }

            img.set(x,y, img.get(offset%img.width, Math.floor(offset/img.width)));
        }
    }
    img.updatePixels();  
    image(img, 0, 0);
    noLoop();
}

function warp(_x, _y, factor, n_range) {
    var n1 = noise((_x + 0.0) * factor, (_y + 0.0) * factor) * n_range;
    var n2 = noise((_x + 5.2) * factor, (_y + 1.3) * factor) * n_range;
    var q = createVector(n1, n2);
    var n3 = noise(((_x + q.x * 4) + 1.7) * factor, ((_y + q.y * 4) + 9.2) * factor) * n_range;
    var n4 = noise(((_x + q.x * 4) + 8.3) * factor, ((_y + q.y * 4) + 2.8) * factor) * n_range;
    var r = createVector(n3, n4);
    return noise((_x + r.x * 4) * factor, (_y + r.y * 4) * factor) * n_range;
}
```